Unable to access SharePoint through PowerAutomate - Unauthorized
So the url provided by external company looks like:
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/AAAA/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?ga=1&id=/sites/AAAA/Shared Documents/BBBB/CCCC/DDDD
I can manually (using the same account) upload files to CCCC and DDDD folders, don't have any permission above this level.
And it always fails with "Unauthorized" error. I cannot select the path as I don't have access to their entire sharepoint so rely on pasting the paths as custom values as below:
(I also tried Site Adress: https://company.sharepoint.com/AAAA and the same error)

Any idea if this is possible to get around? I can't get any more SharePoint permissions sadly.

Can you try to put the site URL in a variable and use that variable in the create file action. Therefore, the folder path will not be dynamic.

Hey, sadly the same issue. Comes back as 401, "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown".
And as it's third party website - I cannot ask them to get any other types of permission.
